# For loop is acting differently

Tags: java

Here is a little code

```
public static void isAscending(String[] array){
    // TODO This function will verify the details of the column if the column contents are actually ascending

    for(String a: array)
        log(a);
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for(String ao: array)
        log(ao);
}
```

In the above, if I just use the first for loop, I get all the elements in the order they were passed. If I put both of them together, I get no output. (Log is a function which does the same as System.out.println)

Am I making some major mistake? 
I cannot see the reason for the second loop to not work

LOG METHOD:

```
public static void log(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

INPUT ARRAY: 
    I am taking the array from a webpage(using Selenium). Here is the function doing that (It works perfectly and gives the output I expect it to be)  :

```
public static String[] getEmail() {
    WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.className(TABLE_RESPONSE));
    List<WebElement>    tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//tr[position()>2]"));
    int i=0;
    String[] emails = new String[tr_collection.size()];
    for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection) {
        WebElement email = trElement.findElement(By.className("email"));
        String email_id = email.getText();
        emails[i] = email_id;
        i++;
    }
    return emails;
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
isAscending(getEmail());
```

Comment: I think you must be making a mistake.  Can you show a log method and the input to isAscending?

Comment: What do you mean by putting both of them together?

Comment: I am sure I am making some major mistake I am mind blown how I am getting the results with one for loop in my code and no results with two. I obviously expect the double.

Comment: The code as is doesn't present problems, it should compile and run with no problems. Probably you missed or added something else, or maybe you're not executing the code you're looking at.

Comment: I am just wondering how was it possible for one for loop to work perfectly then?

Comment: I am wondering that too. But again, seems like you're not executing the code you're seeing. And yes, this can happen.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys!It happened to be a cache issue. There was not anything wrong with the code it was my complier.

Comment: Isn't that embarrassing?

Comment: I don't think is embarrassing. What compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse! I think its JUNO? Not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, it is working, just make sure you are openning and closing your `fors` correctly..
Here is my code sample:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String[] array = new String[10];
        array[0] = "teste1";
        array[1] = "teste2";
        array[2] = "asdf3";
        array[3] = "dfg4";
        array[4] = "xcv";
        array[5] = "324dfg";
        array[6] = "der";
        array[7] = "a";
        array[8] = "sdf1";
        array[9] = "fgdfg7";

        isAscending(array);
    }

    public static void isAscending(String[] array) {

        for (String a : array) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        System.out.println("----------");
        Arrays.sort(array);

        for (String ao : array) {
            System.out.println(ao);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
teste1
teste2
asdf3
dfg4
xcv
324dfg
der
a
sdf1
fgdfg7
----------
324dfg
a
asdf3
der
dfg4
fgdfg7
sdf1
teste1
teste2
xcv
```

Comment: Having just a single line of code should not affect the for loop right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, just wondering if you could have done some mistake and didn't post for us.

Comment: Lol I am the person who asked the question *she

Comment: I know octavian is a guys name.

Comment: Oooops, sorryyy, i edited my answer. If your code still not working, post it completely, add the log function too, then i can help you.

Comment: I did! :) I did add the log function in my post

Comment: Well, i read you whole code, it really doesn't make sense. I see no major problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you were correct my code is perfectly fine. My complier was messed up. All I had to do is "clean" my complier and it worked. I guess caching it? I was beyond mindblown when the code was not working.

Comment: Nice! Depending on your web server, sometimes the .class are not updated, so, when we clean, we are throwing away the .classes and recompiling the project, so, updating everything :)

Comment: cool thanks for letting me know! It is my third week working so that is a good tip